# Is it possible to first apply the maven overlay and then start the build of the project onto which the overlay was applied?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've created a basic Spring web-app which has got some base classes and its own jar dependencies. I will refer it by "basespringapp".
I've created a new Spring web-app which has the "basespringapp" as its maven overlay dependency. I've created new classes in new Spring web-app extending from the base classes of the "basespringapp".
During the maven build of new Spring web-app I want the following:

1. The base classes of "basespringapp" should be copied to my new
   Spring web-app in respective packages (in other words the
   "basespringapp" overlay should be applied first to new Spring
   web-app)
2. The build of the new Spring web-app should start and then
       the repackaging should happen.

The problem is that 2nd step is executing before 1st resulting in compilation errors in new Spring web-app because the base classes present in the "basespringapp" are not available by then.

I was referring to the link:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

The relevant part of the pom.xml of my new Spring web-app is provided below:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.nit.test</groupId>
          <artifactId>basespringapp</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>war</type>
          <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                          <groupId>com.nit.test</groupId>
                          <artifactId>basespringapp</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                        <overlay>
                          <!-- empty groupId/artifactId represents the current build -->
                        </overlay>
                  </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</build>
```